# AS3 Error When Trying To Remove a Movieclip from the Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, removechild

I have an actual movieclip on the main timeline called "img_mc" which I want to remove when a certain frame is hit. So I placed the following code on that frame:
removeChild(img_mc) - even though Flash removes it, I get the following error:

```
 ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
```

I don't understand what I am missing here? I also tried

```
 this.removeChild(img_mc); and

 stage.removeChild(img_mc);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are probably trying to remove it twice, it gets removed the first time but the second time you get an error. It's probably in an enterframe event right?

Comment: Hi BotMaster, yes it's in an enterframe event.

Comment: @user2163224 Take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016602/2256820).

Answer (score 0):

I created a function:

```
function stopTheScript() {
    if (img_mc.parent){
        img_mc.parent.removeChild(img_mc); 
    }
}
```

which seems to work- meaning I don't get an error - however I don't quite understand why? I thought any movieclip placed on the timeline is automatically a child?

Comment: read my comment. If you already removed it once you can't remove it again. Why doesn't that make sense?